# "Right" way to keep API db tables in sync

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, mongoose

It's my first time creating an application solo (back-end, front-end, design) and I could use some guidance on my back-end.

Let's say there is a table of `User`s, `Job`s, and `Application`s (Job Applications). Right now I have it structured like so:

```
UserSchema {
  // other attributes
  _id: String,
  application_ids: [String] // array of String id's 
}

JobSchema {
  // other attributes
  _id: String,
  application_ids: [String]
} 

ApplicationSchema {
  // other attributes
  _id: String,
  applicant_id: String, // the _id of a User
  job_id: String        // the _id of a Job
}
```

My current plan is like when a new `Application` is created (via `POST /api/applications` where I send the User's _id and Job's _id) I would then set the Application's `applicant_id` to the User's _id and then update the User's `application_ids` array as well as the Job's `application_ids` array.

**Question:** Am I going about this in a reasonable manner or am I touching too many tables for one POST request? There are other tables/schemas in my application that will follow a similar relationship structure. Then there's the matter of deleting Applications and then having to update `application_ids` again and etc, etc but that's another matter.

Note: I am using Express.js and Mongoose.js, if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't do it this way.  By storing the ID of the user and job in the application, you can use a query to get all the applications by user or all applications for a given job. No need to touch both.

If you really want to have the relationship on both sides, at least set it up as an ObjectId and use the "ref" declaration.  Check out the populate docs in the mongoose docs.

Comment: Agreed. Currently working with an app that keeps track of the ids on both ends (as `ObjectId` refs, not strings). It's much more of a pain than it's worth. It allows you to use `.populate()` on the array of ids, but it's not worth the overhead of maintaining the references in multiple locations.

Comment: Alright cool, I kinda knew it was probably not the best way to structure it. And now that you mention it, you're right. I could just scan through all `Application`s, checking their `applicant_id` or `job_id`. Thank you!

Comment: @dvlsg Also you mentioned that doing it this way is not really worth it. Just curious, are you going to change the way you structure your app? Or do the advantages outweigh the disadvantages for your particular case?

Comment: I would *like* to change it. The advantages of readily available `populate()` calls definitely do not outweigh the disadvantages of having to manually maintain referential integrity, in my opinion. That ship may have already sailed for me, though. Truth be told, in your scenario, I would question the use of mongodb at all, since the data definitely appears to be relational.

Comment: @dvlsg Honestly, I agree with you. It's just there seems to be so many resources and examples readily available for Express.js + Mongoose.js apps since it's so user-friendly and easy to pick up. I do think that a relational database would be much, much better. Would you have any recommendations?

Comment: Sure - if you like the batteries-included style of mongoose as well as the json style of query syntax, I would strongly suggest [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/). There will be some additional work -- namely with setting up associations (since they aren't actually a thing in mongodb), but the methods are reasonably straight forward if you understand the relationships in the data. For the database itself, I would suggest postgres, but I'll often use sqlite just to get my project off the ground, then migrate later.